# How to access RouterConfig from Component (Angular2 RC4)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

What is the preferred way to access the RouterConfig from an Angular 2 Component.  I would like to examine all the child routes of my current route.

The best I've been able to come up with is accessing a private member variable of the ActivatedRouteSnapshot (**_routeConfig**).  But would rather not use that since it is subject to change.

See code snippet below:

```
export class MyComponent{

  constructor(private _router: Router,
            private _route: ActivatedRoute)
  {

  }

  private findChildRoute(componentPath : string){
    let matchingRoute = (<any>this._route.snapshot)._routeConfig.children.find((T) => T.path == componentPath );
    return matchingRoute;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access full router tree using.

```
this.router.routerState // tree of activated routers
```

Now you can use children to find all child routes state `ActivatedRoute`

```
constructor(private router:Router, private currentActivatedRoute:ActivatedRoute)
// this should be called in ngOnInit
    var state = this.router.routerState
    var children = state.children(this.currentActivatedRoute)
```

[RouterState](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/router/src/router_state.ts#L17-L48), [Tree](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/router/src/utils/tree.ts)

Comment: this was useful but does not fully answer the question.  your suggestion does not return all defined child routes from the parent component. Instead It returns an array with the only active child route.